# Unit testing concrete services extending generic service

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

Infrastructure I set up is based on generic service and generic repository. Right now I am trying to write unit tests and I am having some challenges. Here is the code:

IBaseRepository:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T Add(T entity, bool saveChanges = true);
    //more generic code
}
```

IServiceBase:

```
public interface IServiceBase<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity Create(TEntity entity);
    //more generic code
}
```

BaseRepository:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _dbContext;

    public BaseRepository(DatabaseContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public T Add(T entity, bool saveChanges = true)
    {
        _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        if (saveChanges) _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return entity;
    }
}
```

ServiceBase:

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<TEntity, TRepository> : IServiceBase<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
        where TRepository : BaseRepository<TEntity>
{
    public TRepository Repository;

    public ServiceBase(BaseRepository<TEntity> rep)
    {
        Repository = (TRepository)rep;
    }

    public long Count(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereCondition)
    {
        return Repository.GetAll().AsQueryable().Where(whereCondition).Count();
    }
}
```

AddressService (Concrete domain service):

```
 public class AddressService : ServiceBase<Address, BaseRepository<Address>>, IAddressService
 {
    public AddressService(BaseRepository<Address> rep) : base(rep)
    {
    }

    public VerifyAddress()
    {
        //custom logic...
    }
 }
```

Test:

```
public class AddressTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void VerifyAddress()
    {
        var baseRepository = new Mock<BaseRepository<Address>>();
        var addressService = new AddressService(baseRepository.Object);            

        var test = addressService.Verify();
        Assert.NotNull(test);
    }
}
```

The error I get is `Message: Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: Repositories.Repositories.BaseRepository. Could not find a parameterless constructor.`

I am aware why I am getting this error. The reason is because BaseRepository has constructor which expects `DatabaseContext` as a parameter.

My question would be is it possible to unit test `AddressService` with setup like this?

Comment: What happens if you add a parameterless constructor to the `BaseRepository` and run your test?

Comment: Why is `AddressService` expecting a `BaseRepository` as input and not an `IBaseRepository`? Changing that should fix your issue (of course you should mock `IBaseRepository` then)

Comment: Is it a good practice to add an parameterless constructor just in order to complete the unit tests? When I added it, it threw an ``System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`` in ``BaseRepository`` because ``_dbContext`` is null and every operation to database requires that property because nothing is mocked on that side

Comment: I see the problem somewhere else, try mocking DatabaseContext (wrap it with an interface first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are trying to utilize the benefits of dependency injection, which is good. However, at the moment you are using `BaseRepository` as the dependency rather than `IBaseRepository` which makes `IBaseRepository` kinda redundant and couples your classes tightly to a specific implementation (`BaseRepository`). This also means that you have a hard dependency on `DatabaseContext` because that's required to instatiate a `BaseRepository`. If you go back one step and utilize `IBaseRepository` for a more loose coupling you will at the same time avoid the dependency on `DatabaseContext` and thus make unit testing easier as well.

First, change the definition of your `ServiceBase`:

```
public abstract class ServiceBase<TEntity, TRepository> : IServiceBase<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
        where TRepository : IBaseRepository<TEntity>
{
    public TRepository Repository { get; private set; }

    public ServiceBase(TRepository rep)
    {
        Repository = rep;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then the `AddressService`:

```
public class AddressService : ServiceBase<Address, IBaseRepository<Address>>, IAddressService
{
    public AddressService(IBaseRepository<Address> rep) : base(rep)
    {
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now you no longer depend on `DatabaseContext` and can unit test `AddressService` much simpler (the same way you were planning):

```
public class AddressTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void VerifyAddress()
    {
        var baseRepository = new Mock<IBaseRepository<Address>>();
        var addressService = new AddressService(baseRepository.Object);            

        var test = addressService.Verify();
        Assert.NotNull(test);
    }
}
```